# How to authenticate SharePoint Rest API calls from c# back end? (Read details)

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, sharepoint

I am trying simple application which listens for http requests and makes rest api calls to Sharepoint 2013.

**Scenario:**

---

A user makes a get request from the browser to the back-end (which is in c#). The sharepoint api is called from back-end. Now it should use the logged in users credentials for this request but I get unauthorized error.

Calling rest api directly from browser works.

Note :
Users are authenticated with AD so I don't want to request credentials again in my app.
Most solutions that I find assume that user is logged in on the machine making rest calls (back-end) but its different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Security header is mandatory to call SharePoint API. You have different ways to get the AccessToken, including pure HTTP calls to ADFS or login.microsoft, but I do think you need it.

A sample using native Client Context.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(someSharePointUrl);
clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += delegate (object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Bearer {0}", someUserToken);
};
//... then use clientContext as usual
```

A sample using more usual REST call, also including formDigest

```
HttpWebRequest itemRequest =
    (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(hostUrl + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items");
itemRequest.Method = "POST";
itemRequest.ContentLength = itemPostBody.Length;
itemRequest.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
itemRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
itemRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
itemRequest.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);
```

Other option is to use AppOnlyToken, but you then have impersonate calls to API and need to manage User ID yourself !

Comment: Thanks for the input @Albo,  the issue is getting access token only, I don't want to redirect users to internet, need an intranet only solution. I don't know much about ADFS, can you please explain how to approach that.